# simple scan takes forever to come up

Tags: 13.10, scanner

I think it might be after the upgrade to 13.10 but simple scan is taking forever to respond. I looked with System Monitor and it is wait_on_page or wait_on_buffer or a few other things.
When I try to quit, generally I have to force quit.

I tried to remove it and reinstall it, but that didn't help. It used to work very well and I don't understand what went wrong. Suppose I remove it again. Is there something else which I need to kill? Any other suggestions on what to do to bring it back to life?

Thanks,
Ilan

Comment: You have to totally remove it using Synaptic, otherwise the config files still will be present. Reboot after the removal. Then install it again.

Comment: Your answer was intriguing because it was simple and made sense. I just tried it and it seems the problem is somewhere else, maybe even a bug. (I have to prove it is a bug before reporting it.) Xsane works just fine so I am using xsane in place of simple scan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be a bug in the current version of Simple Scan for 13.10. I'm having the same problem in 13.10 with the same hardware I had in 13.04--as well as previous versions of Ubuntu--with which Simple Scan worked flawlessly.

If you read through this [Launchpad Bug Report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/simple-scan/+bug/1245678), you will see that the issue has already been reported, triaged, and a fix added upstream. There's also a workaround in that report that you could try if you like.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For the moment the simplest scan is just to use xsane. That still works fine.